# Can you entangle two electrical fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electric-fields, quantum-entanglement

Lets say I have two already existing electrical fields. can I entangle them and cause one to influence another. (see image)[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you created a pair of entangled water molecules. Water molecules are polar, meaning they have an electric dipole moment. Let's denote two possible states of the water molecule as $|\uparrow \rangle$, meaning the electric dipole is up along some axis, and an orthogonal state $| \downarrow \rangle$ meaning the dipole is down. Then put the two molecules in the state
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow \downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow \uparrow\rangle\right)
\end{equation}
Then if we widely separate the two entangled water molecules, the state of the electric field in the regions near the water molecules will also be entangled, since a dipole $\vec{p}$ creates an electric field $\vec{E} \propto - \vec{p}$ along the axis of the dipole.